# UWP In app purchase query

Tags: win-universal-app

Hopefully some one will know the answer.

I've been the developing a 3d modelling win-10 universal app which is going to include in app purchases.

What I'd preferably like to happen is that the customer can purchase models, textures, new tools etc via the in-app purchase mechanism.

What I need to know does everything have to be included in the original app or does the in app purchase actually add new code,models etc to the original app.?

If so where is the in-app purchase package uploaded to?

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation that answers this question

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on user's in-app purchases will be available to you through the 
[LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.productlicenses.aspx) property as a collection of [ProductLicense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlicense.aspx) objects. Each object contains basic information about the purchase like ID and expiration date. It means that it cannot contain any data related to your app.

You should include everting in the original app or you may put purchase related data (lets say your models and textures) on a web server and allow the app to download it after purchasing each in-app product. You can also [very the receipt of purchases on the web server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases) before providing data to clients.